# Schedule Maintenance Plan - Request For a Good Sequence

Tags: sql-server, maintenance, ola-hallengren

I have installed Ola Hallengren's MaintenanceSolution.sql script.

So what I'll get out-of-the-box are a lot of jobs:

[image: Olla Hallengren SQL Maintenance Jobs]

My questions is:

What schedules should I implement based on the jobs that are provided with the script?

The SQL-Full Backup starts on Saturday at 11:00 pm. So I thought I would use the following schedules:

```
Job                           Schedule
----------------------------- ------------------------
IndexOptimize                 Saturday at 10:00 pm  
Database IntegrityCheck       Saturday at 09:00 pm  
CommandLog Cleanup            Sunday at 03:00 am  
Output File Cleanup           Sunday at 03:15 am  
SP_delte_backuphistory        Sunday at 03:20 am  
SP_purge_Jobhistory           Sunday at 03:25 am
```

What's your advice?

Every comment is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your goal is to "chain" certain jobs: to run an integrity check, then an index optimization, then a backup.

First - it *may* make sense to take a backup *before* the check and index optimization. If something were to go horribly wrong during those steps, you could get back to the start to try to resolve things. If you take differential backups of this DB, you might want to take a final diff backup before, and a full backup after.

Second, the chaining seems reasonable in general. However, until you've run the jobs, you have no idea how long they'll take. If there's a chance that the DB check and the index optimization could take longer than an hour, I'd space things out more. Overlapping these things isn't necessarily a good idea.

If the tightest possible chaining is desirable, then move the job steps into a single job, and order them as desired. Or, as suggested by [@AaronBertrand](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1186/aaron-bertrand), only set and actual schedule for the first job; have the first job kick off the second as its final step, the second job kick off the third, and so forth.

Comment: And even if you pad by an hour, there will be occasions where it takes 5 hours longer. Instead of scheduling the second job, might make sense to have the first job kick off the second job as its last step (in case the jobs need to be managed separately or the logic is complex enough to make pulling them as steps into the first job is cumbersome)

Answer (score 1):

Well so I see there is a vote to close afoot here, and it makes sense - this is an opinion based question. There is no right or wrong answer here. But before the close votes come in - a few things for you to consider:

1. There are no hard and fast rules about the order here.
2. The purge and history cleanup jobs (on a system that doesn't have years of history that was never purged) are generally very quick. I typically schedule those weekly at midnight on a Friday or Saturday - and it just works, they may take seconds to single-digit minutes for most systems. You could even do them at 8AM on Saturday or Sunday after all is done.
3. Those jobs won't really cause issues or break our database. So they can run independently of worrying about those. Hopefully, you are in full recovery and doing log backups.
4. The only real hard and fast rule I use is: A.) I don't delete my backup until I know my next one is good B.) I always verify and use checksum (and test restore when I am able), C.) I do my full backup AFTER my checkdbs each week - so I know when I have a good checkdb, I have a good backup right after it. D.) I keep my full backups, log backups and any diff backups since my last good checkdb so I can always get back when needed (I explained this in a rather long-winded - sorry - blog post about [Corruption resistant backup strategies](https://straightpathsql.com/archives/2017/01/sql-server-corruption-read/).)

Comment: I would actually do the purge before all the weekend work, that way if something goes wrong *during* that weekend work, you've got all the history. If jobs fail and *then* you clean up all the job and backup history, and try to diagnose after the fact...

Comment: Sure but I'm not doing a purge including this weekend. I'm doing the purge with 2-3 weeks back so we still have the recent history :)

Comment: Ah ok, I'd add that detail to bullet 2. :-)